Dropdown to select tokens (and containing html block) not appearing when editing event onling registration
New Installation under Wordpress.
When editing e.g. the confirmation email, I see only the CKEditor, and not the select2 component, where I can select a token.
In other places, e.g. when editing the mail templates, I see this block as expected.
Is there some template I need to update?
Thanks in advance.

Could be a theme conflict with your wordpress theme? Check browser dev console for errors.
